# Is it possible to rollback test database in ASP.NET Core?

Tags: c#, asp.net, database, testing, transactions

I'm building a test suite for the web application.
I introduce some integration tests.

And what I'm about to do is

- to create the fixtures to seed the database before the tests
- to revert the database to the original state once the tests are done (rollback?)
- (nice to have) to rollback the database to the newly seeded state before every test

**What's the approach in ASP.NET Core for this sort of thing?**

I've already found `v-zubritsky/Reseed` library but it looks like a bit handicraft. I feel that I miss some solid approach to that thing.

Comment: Wouldn't it be easier and less depending on a Database by using mocking. Take look at `NSubstitute` or `Moq`

Comment: @PaulSinnema if we are talking about unit tests, then yes. But what if I'd like to have a pre-seeded database with all the relational complexity in it already? It would be quite hard to mo(q)ck. I'd better write some data in it in the regular way.

Answer (score 0):

You can always dockerize your database at the starting state and compose it again after tests finish.

Or you can run your tests in transaction and do not commit it in the end of the test.

Anyway think about it differently - test data is not too bad in dev/test environments. When you run your integration tests while you developing then you have a lot of test data in db and then you can check performance of your app.

Comment: Thanks, and yes, I understand the profit of having some data in the test database, but what I wanted to achieve is the possibility to just run the test like "GET /someEp" and be sure that some data is already in the place and would be successfully read. Otherwise I would have to add the data before at every test, but that could be avoided.

Comment: Still i think the best pattern is to arrange test data IN the test not before. You should use mocking pattern or insert data to db while test runs and use Transaction (wihout commiting it if you do not want this data in db after test runs). 

When you put test data in arrangment step then you have whole process of test in one place an you didnt have to worry of any coupling